# Is it possible to create a class template and select a C# property when the function is called?

Tags: c#, templates

Does anyone know if the following is possible to pass in a List<> of objects to a function and specify which property the function should use within each object that its working with ?

I have a class that works with a specific property of an object throughout the class, but I dont want to create multiple copies of the same class to work with different properties of that object. I thought about using Linq, but I dont see a way to specify which property to use in other functions of the manipulation class.

I was thinking there has to be a more elegant way to do this instead of creating the same class to handle each property. I thought about using Reflection to tell the function which property to work with but that gets ugly really quick

Example psuedo code :

```
class Store
{
   int amount;
   int id;
   int serial;
}

class AggregationMethods
{
   bool Has3Values( List<Store> places /* some other param to specify which property to use*/)
   {
      // do something with Store.amount or Store.id
   }

   // other functions to work with Store.amount or Store.id or Store.serial

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case, they're all `int` values - so you could just retain a `Func<Store, int>` or pass it into each method. It becomes slightly harder if you need to work over multiple types, but we don't really have enough information to comment further.

It's also not clear whether you would expect two have multiple *instances* of `AggregationMethods` (e.g. one for amounts, one for IDs etc) or whether these would really be static methods. If you're using instances, then you could keep the projection as a member variable, and apply it within each method.

It's worth noting that the properties you've given probably don't really make sense to apply the same aggregations - for example, while summing amounts makes sense, it's meaningless to sum IDs.

Comment: Jon ! Thanks for the response. I just made up that code to illustrate my point. I'm not really doing aggregation, but I do need  to have a class manipulate the value of another class's properties. Dont get caught up in the names, as they are arbitrary. The function name was random, I basically have a class that I use to manipulate one of the members of the Store class. I have about 8 functions that manipulate a particular Store class member. I would expect to have multiple instances of the AggregatorMethods class.

Comment: @AriesOntheHorizon: As ever, one of the keys to getting a useful answer is providing a relevant example :) It sounds like you *may* want to make `AggregationMethods` generic, taking a `Func<Store, T>` in the constructor, where `T` is the type of the projection result. I hope that helps - but if it doesn't, please provide a more concrete, realistic example and I'll see what I can do.